# Can a spatial index be created on a geography column in a table variable

Tags: indexing, sql-server-2014

I am familiar with the syntax to create an index inline when declaring a table variable, but **I am unable to create an inline spatial index on a geography field** in a table variable.

I am trying to achieve the following (which I do not think is an option as the index is created after declaring the table variable), **i.e:**

```sql
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX SDX_xTD_eGeog ON @T ( C1 ) 
USING GEOGRAPHY_GRID WITH 
( 
   GRIDS=(LEVEL_1 = HIGH,LEVEL_2 = HIGH,LEVEL_3 = HIGH,LEVEL_4 = HIGH), 
   CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 64, 
   PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
   SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
   DROP_EXISTING = OFF, 
   ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
   ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON 
) ;
```

on a column in a table variable, by doing:

```sql
CREATE TABLE @T
(
   [objid] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
  ,Name    NVARCHAR(255) INDEX ix_name NONCLUSTERED
  ,C1      GEOGRAPHY.......... here is where i need to add the spacial 
                               index, but the syntax does not work:
                               SPATIAL INDEX SDX_xTD_eGeog  
                               USING GEOGRAPHY_GRID WITH 
                               ( 
                                   GRIDS=(LEVEL_1 = HIGH,LEVEL_2 = HIGH,LEVEL_3 = HIGH,LEVEL_4 = HIGH), 
                                   CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 64, 
                                   PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
                                   SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
                                   DROP_EXISTING = OFF, 
                                   ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                                   ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON 
                               )
)
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and update formatting of your sample script?

Comment: Why are you unable to create the index? What happens with the given code?